# MediaElement cannot be showed when its Gris has a white background

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, background-color, mediaelement

I write a simple code in VS2010 (Windows Phone APP):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">      
            <MediaElement x:Name="ttt" Source="/Video/2.wmv"/>
</Grid>
```

When the Background is set to 'White', there is nothing can be showed. But when the Background is 'Transparent', I can see the video. I tried to use Canvas.ZIndex() to set the Z value. But it doesn't work.

Who can help me to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but looks like that MediaElement uses parent in some way. It is nice room for investigation. Moreover small googling shows other similar bug - [Windows Phone 7: Silverlight MediaElement has a transparent background in emulator](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/615386/windows-phone-7-silverlight-mediaelement-has-a-transparent-background-in-emulator).

About your case. Try to add one more container. Something like next:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">      
      <Grid x:Name="MediaLayout" Background="Transparent"> 
            <MediaElement x:Name="ttt" Source="/Video/2.wmv"/>
       </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have tried your method on my simulator. But it still doesn't work. Perhaps, I should run it on device to have a try.